# How come my panel is not showing itself?

Tags: java, jpanel, grid-layout, border-layout

After the click of a button, I have my code so that a new panel shows up with new components, however, on the click of a button, it does not show.

I believe I have made it show, but I'm still unsure as to why it's not showing at all.

Here's my code:

```
            JPanel panelTest = new JPanel();
            JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 2));

            JLabel firstNameLabel = new JLabel("First Name: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
            JLabel lastNameLabel = new JLabel("Last Name: ", JLabel.RIGHT);

            JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField lastNameField = new JTextField(10);

            centerPanel.add(firstNameLabel);
            centerPanel.add(firstNameField);
            centerPanel.add(lastNameLabel);
            centerPanel.add(lastNameField);

            panelTest.add(centerPanel);
```

How exactly should I be getting my panel to show on the click of a button? Because once I click it, nothing shows. Other code works for the button, I just cannot get this panel to show with text fields and all.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to add `panelTest` to your main frame as well.

Comment: without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) we cannot exactly tell what your problem meight be.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

where frame is what you names you JFrame. I had this problem and had to do this whenever I added things to my JFrame after I set it to visible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you jave no `JFrame` to hold your panel.
Create a JFrame, then add your panel with `jframe.add(panelTest);`